# Should augmented basis be used for Hirshfeld charges?

Tags: basis-sets, charge-density, conceptual-dft, multiwfn

I'm calculating condensed Fukui functions to explain the reactivity of my molecules.

The manual for Multiwfn suggests using atomic dipole moment corrected Hirshfeld charges for it. However I get strange results, on some atoms in which $f^+$ is negative.

**I'm using def2-TZVPD basis set, and I'm wondering if diffuse functions can make Hirshfeld charges meaningless as they do for Mulliken charges?**

Comment: Some comments were moved to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58384527#58384527) (including a link to [this related question](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1094/5)). Also what @AndrewRosen is talking about is related to [this answer by Susi](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1441/7).

Comment: Hirshfeld charges are known to be problematic; you should use modern iterative approaches like iterative Stockholder, instead...

Comment: I recommend Minimum Basis iterative Stockholder (MBIS) charges

Comment: Do you have a reference that says that augmenting a basis set causes Mulliken charges to change from meaningful to "meaningless"?